# PHP preg_match with a single character string

Tags: php, regex

I am having trouble with a regex (which is definitely not my forte, so be gentle with me)

This fails to match:

```
    preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z].[a-zA-Z0-9\ _]*$/', 'n');
```

and I cannot see why. It seems OK on strings of more than one character, just when it is a single character it does not match.

I am trying to ensure my string starts with a letter(upper or lower case) followed by 0 or more characters which are each one of: letter(upper or lower case), digit, space or underscore.

Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks

Comment: That is because you need at least 2 characters. The fist one is matched by `[a-zA-Z]`, and the second by `.` You can see by yourself with http://regex101.com.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern actually requires that at least *two* characters be present:

```
^[a-zA-Z].[a-zA-Z0-9\ _]*$
```

The `[a-zA-Z]` term matches a letter, and the following dot `.` matches a single other character.  So the following call would succeed, with a two character string:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z].[a-zA-Z0-9\ _]*$/', 'nn');
```

If you intended to create a pattern which would match a leading letter, followed by zero or more letters, numbers, backslash, space, or underscore, then consider using the following:

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\ _]*$/', 'n');
```

Here, I have removed the dot, so now the above call would succeed.

Comment: That solves my problem. I obviously need to get a better understanding than I currently have. Thank you both.